# Dismiss a pushed view controller on current tab before switching to a different tab in UITabbarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, pushviewcontroller

I have tabbarcontroller with three tabs and nav1, nav2, nav3 as their navigationContollers. After pushing a new viewcontroller(pVC) onto the rootViewController of nav1, I click on second or third tab, then how can I dismiss the pushedViewController pVC before secondTabs nav2's rootVC appears?
Below is how tabar is setup

```
tabbar.setViewControllers([
                nav1,
                nav2,
                nav3
            ]
            .compactMap({ $0.toPresent }),
            animated: false
        )
```

Comment: You should improve your question. If you do not improve other users do not help your problem.

Comment: @EmreDeğirmenci I improved it so it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how iOS works. Users have an expectation that their tab hierarchies remain intact when selecting a different tab. What is the purpose of popping each time a different tab is selected? Perhaps your UI model should actually be a modal presentation or some other kind of interaction.

Given that, if you insist on upsetting your users by violating the HIG, you can do so by becoming the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and implementing `tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)`. In here, do your pop to root, then return `true`. Keep in mind this is a synchronous function. Making this animated is non-trivial as there are no good hooks into `UINavigationController`'s animations. There is no completion handler, etc. like there is for modal presentations. Here is the non-animated version:

```swift
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
  // you need a reference to your nav controller
  if let navController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
    navController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
  }

  return true 
}
```